# Group by count(*) and 0 instead of empty

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, isnull

I have an SQL request like this:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") as date, Count(*) as total from users 
where `user_date_accountcreated` 
BETWEEN '2016-09-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-03 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%y%m%d")
```

But when there is no reccords, I have empty result because of `GROUP BY`, there is nothing to group...

I tried with `ISNULL` like this:

```
SELECT date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") as date, ISNULL(Count(*), 0) as total from users 
where `user_date_accountcreated` BETWEEN '2016-09-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-03 23:59:59'
GROUP BY date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%y%m%d")
```

But I get an SQL error: #1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Any chance to get 0 instead of empty result when we use a `GROUP BY` ?

Comment: count() is an aggregate function. its result is not available until AFTER all rows have been considered. You're using it in an isnull() function, which gets evaluated on a per-row basis. Databases cannot time travel, therefore they cannot retroactively provide a "final" count(*) value to isnull at the time the isnull is actually evaluated. and of course, RTFM: [isnull()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) it only takes ONE argument, exactly as your error says.

Comment: you probably want [coalesce()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) instead.

Comment: @MarcB I think his problem is that the `WHERE` condition is filtering off records completely, leaving his result set missing certain data over time, because it did not match the criteria.  Checking for 0, null, etc., won't bear fruit because the records simply won't be there.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(user_date_accountcreated, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN user_date_accountcreated BETWEEN '2016-09-18 00:00:00' AND
                                                  '2016-10-03 23:59:59'
            THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_from_users
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(user_date_accountcreated, "%y%m%d")
```

Comment: I get strange results starting at 2014-01-01 as date (The beginning of the dates in the table) until 2014-01-25 and all results are NULL.

Comment: @LondonSmith Please try again, I modified the `CASE` statement to return a sum of `0` if there are no matching records for a given group.  Previously, I had omitted this, which could explain why you were getting `NULL` values in places you did not expect.

Answer (score 1):

First of all a query can not return records that are not there. If you want to see them, you'd have to generate them. The following query uses UNION ALL to either get the records from your query or a generated record when your query returns no rows:

```
SELECT 
  date_format(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM users 
WHERE user_date_accountcreated >= '2016-09-18' 
  AND user_date_accountcreated < '2016-10-04' 
GROUP BY date_format(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d')
UNION ALL
SELECT null, 0
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_date_accountcreated >= '2016-09-18' 
    AND user_date_accountcreated < '2016-10-04' 
);
```

The same can be achieved with a with clause:

```
WITH mydates AS
(
  SELECT 
    date_format(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d') AS date, 
    COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM users 
  WHERE user_date_accountcreated >= '2016-09-18' 
    AND user_date_accountcreated < '2016-10-04' 
  GROUP BY date_format(user_date_accountcreated, '%Y-%m-%d')
)
SELECT date, total FROM mydates
UNION ALL
SELECT null, 0 WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from mydates);
```

I've also corrected two mistakes in your query:

- The SQL string delimiter is `'` as in `'%Y-%m-%d'`.
- Your select list should contain the same value as in group by (`'%Y-%m-%'` vs. `'%y%m%d'`). It works in your case, but could cause problems in other situations.

Comment: Yes I understand my 2 mistakes. For the results, I don't get dates with 0, they just don't appear.

Comment: @LondonSmith If your original table is missing records for certain dates, then those dates absolutely won't be appearing in any of the solutions given.  In this case, you might have to use a calendar table to bring in missing data.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen I will do the stuff in PHP instead of using a calendar. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
SELECT
  date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") as date, 
  Count( date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%Y-%m-%d") )  as total
from users 
where `user_date_accountcreated` 
BETWEEN '2016-09-18 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-03 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY date_format(`user_date_accountcreated`, "%y%m%d")
```

Comment: No differences, dates width no results don't appear.